# Django index page best/most common practice

Tags: python, django, indexing

I am working on a site currently (first one solo) and went to go make an index page. I have been attempting to follow django best practices as I go, so naturally I go search for this but couldn't a real standard in regards to this.

I have seen folks creating apps to serve this purpose named various things (main, home, misc) and have seen a views.py in the root of the project. I am really just looking for what the majority out there do for this.

The index page is not static, since I want to detect if the user is logged in and such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If all of your dynamic content is handled in the template (for example, if it's just simple checking if a user is present on the request), then I recommend using a generic view, specificially the [direct to template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) view:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'index.html'}),
)
```

If you want to add a few more bits of information to the template context, there is another argument, `extra_context`, that you can pass to the generic view to include it:

```
extra_context = { 
    'foo': 'bar',
    # etc
}
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'index.html', 'extra_context': extra_context }),
)
```

Comment: I ended up using this method. After conversing with my local django user group they also agreed this was the best method.

Comment: This is being deprecated, a better option is:
`from django.views.generic import TemplateView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),`

Comment: @StaticX Perhaps the above comment warrants itself to be in a separate answer? It could certainly help with the formatting. Thanks!

Comment: It's only applicable to Django before 1.5. New way is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117835/django-1-5-index-page

Answer (score 3):

I tend to create a `views.py` in the root of the project where I keep the `index` view.

Comment: From what others have said, it seems that this is the second best option, if you need a full view instead of just direct_to_template.