# django how to use template for the site's home page

Tags: python, django

Here's my folder structure (all blacked out is just name of project, just assume 'myproject'):

[image]

I want to set my home page, ie `http://mydomain.com/`, as a template HTML. So following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940528/django-index-page-best-most-common-practice), I set this as my `url.py` in my `myproject` project folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView 

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^events/', include('events.urls', namespace='events')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

But Django keeps trying to append this path to the events folder. The `DEBUG = True` output from the browser indicates that it cannot find this template at

```
/home/ubuntu/django/myproject/events/templates/templates/myproject/index.html
```

which of course is not what I was trying to point to. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Django will try to find `index.html` template at various folders that you have specified in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` settings and in `templates` folder in each app if `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting have `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'`

More details information at [Loading Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates)

Comment: yes but I have other templates in app template folder named `index.html` that I don't want getting confused. is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @lollercoaster, I don't that will work for you, because django will pick one whichever comes first. So it will always pick one, even if you want 2nd one. Unless you discriminate either by name (use _home.html_) or by path (put in _templates/project/index.html_ and refer as _project/index.html_)

Comment: ok, so I'm still confused how I include that in my `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`, can I use the inlclude function?

Comment: the index.html template so that it is the template that appears at `http://mydomain.com/`

Comment: @lollercoaster, Rename `index.html` to `home.html` and update urls.py accordingly.

Comment: I started using django two days ago...I don't know what line to put in urls.py. do I use an `include()` call or the `TemplateView` solution posted elsewhere on SO?

Comment: any ideas for the best solution?

Comment: @lollercoaster, as I said best would be to change file name. I don't think it can get simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the TEMPLATE_DIRS and try to use absolute paths like this:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
...
```

If you have some application and your template's folder located as another folder, then you can define the TEMPLATE_DIRS in this manner:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'events', 'templates'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
...
```

And don't forget to change your views to render the template, something like this:

```
...
return render_to_response('events/index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
...
```

EDIT:

And change your project's urls something like this:

```
from events import urls
...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^events/', include('events.urls', namespace='events')),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make single templates directory on the same level as your apps.
 For example:

```
/home/ubuntu/django/myproject/templates/events
```

```
/home/ubuntu/django/myproject/templates/some_other_app
```

Also, check TEMPLATE_DIRS in your settings file, here is working example:

```
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, normpath

DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates')),
)
```

Comment: if I have other template directories in app folders, how do I ensure different templates with same name don't get confused? and what do I put in the project-leve `urls.py` file?